# how to give base url in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

i was succeed create ajax, but that only working after i running php artisan servee, i need to put base url in my ajax

```
$('#province').change(function (e) { 
       var prov = $('#province').val();
       //panggil ajax
       $.ajax({ 
           type: "GET",
           url: "/city/"+ prov,
           //data: tidak perlu mengirim data karena oop
           success: function (response) {
               $('#city').html(response);
           }
       });  
    });
```

url i have change to

```
var base_url = '{!! url().'/' !!}';

url: bar_url +"/city/"+ prov,
```

but still code above not working asses url

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: if you js code is separate not inside the `.blade` file then it is not gonna work..try `var base_url = '{{URL::to("/")}}';`

Comment: Can you share more details? What **exactly** is not working with the given code? Is there any error message given?

Answer (score 0):

The Standard way of Base URL is putting Base URL in HTML > Head > base Tag

```
<base href="{{url()}}" target="_blank">
```

Then your all Ajax requests will be having the base url from this tag without any extra code of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

if your js code is inside the .blade file then try this

```
 url: "{{ route("city/"+ prov) }}"
```

Or in js file you can add this in .blade file

`var base_url = '{{URL::to("/")}}';`

and in js file add this `url: base_url`

Answer (score 0):

just replace your code with my code

```
$.ajax({ 
           type: "GET",
           url: '{{ url("/")}}' + "/city/"+ prov,
           //data: tidak perlu mengirim data karena oop
           success: function (response) {
               $('#city').html(response);
           }
       });
```